# Ruby/Rails. Passing variable into parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a lot pages in my app. And for every page I need to create a new variable and describe method. And if I will need to change something, I will have to change on every page. So the idea is to create universal method in `application_controller.rb`.

For example, I have a lot of categories in my Posts and to target some category for page I did: `@posts_for_interesting = Post.where(interesting: true)`, other category, for example: `@posts_for_photos = Post.where(photos: true)`.

And the `application_controller.rb`, have to look something like that:

```
def posts_for_all_pages(category)
  @posts = Posts.where(category: true)
end
```

And, for example, `photos_controller.rb` must look like that:

```
posts_for_all_pages(photos)
```

And how can I pass this `photos` to `Post.where(category: true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right here in your original code:

```
def posts_for_all_pages(category)
  @posts = Posts.where(category: true)
end
```

The `category` in `Posts.where(category: true)` will **not** a variable, it will be a hard coded symbol `:category`, so it won't work. Instead, write this:

```
def posts_for_all_pages(category)
  @posts = Posts.where(category => true)
end
```

a small change, but definitely has a different meaning.

Then when you call the method, you pass a symbol to it:

```
posts_for_all_pages(:photos)
```